# Middleware que salva um user_id após uma requisição no adonis.js/node.js

Tags: node.js, adonisjs

Eu possuo a seguinte tabela job:

```
job
--------------
id INTEGER PK,
name VARCHAR,
user_id INTEGER FK
```

Eu preciso salvar na coluna `user_id` o id do usuário que criou aquele registro.
Eu tentei criar este middleware:

```
'use strict'

class Auditory{
  async handle ({ request, auth }, next) {

    const userLogged= await auth.getUser()
    const idUser= userLogged.id

    request.user_id = idUser


    await next()
  }
}
```

module.exports = Auditoria
Eu coloquei um `console.log()` dentro do Auditory class, então eu sei que esse midlware está sendo chamado quando eu faço a requisição, porém o `user_id` não está sendo salvo no banco de dados.

Se eu coloco um `console.log()` no idUser eu obtenho o valor correto do id esperado, porém ao consultar no banco o que foi salvo, o `user_id` é null.

Estou esquecendo algo?

Eu não recebo do frontend o `user_id`, ficando por conta do backend salvar este dado através do token.

**@Edit:**

Gravação conforme solicitado:

```
async store ({ request }){

    let job= request.all()
    job = await Job.create(job)
    return job

}
```

Comment: Está vindo `null` ? coloque um `console.log(userLogged)` verifique o que retornou

Comment: não, o retorno da variável userLogged e idUsuario está conforme o esperado. O problema é que eu seto ele no request e ele salva como null, tentei settar no request.body e request antes e depois do await next() mas ambos os casos salvam o user_id como null

Comment: Coloque a parte da gravação?

Comment: `let job = request.all()`? aqui vem o valor? `user_id`?

Comment: "Eu não recebo do frontend o user_id, ficando por conta do backend salvar este dado através do token."

Comment: Isso eu sei `"Eu não recebo do frontend o user_id, ficando por conta do backend salvar este dado através do token."`? você pode resgatar no front - end somente o que precisa, dando um `return (request.all());` para ver o que ele retorna! entendeu

Comment: não estamos na mesma linha de raciocínio

Comment: o request.all() não possui o user_id

Comment: Então você testou? `request.all() não possui o user_id`?

Comment: não, minha ideia é colocar ele através do backend antes de salvar

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100527/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-veronesecoms).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a ajuda do @Virgilio Novic consegui chegar no resultado esperado através da seguinte implementação:

Criei esse middleware:

```
class Auditoria {
    async handle ({ request, auth, }, next) {

        const usuarioLogado = await auth.getUser()

        request.user_id = usuarioLogado.id
        await next()   
    }
}
```

No meu store eu crio um objeto user com os dados do request.all() e acrescento o user_id que veio do middleware:

```
async store ({ request }){

    const user = {...request.all(), user_id: request.user_id};
    const response = await User.create(user)

    return response

}
```

Meu principal problema foi achar que o request.all() iria conter o user_id do middleware, porém, o método `request.all()` é um método que não pega o dinamico criado pelo request do middleware.